# Proving existence of a linear functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(X, \| \cdot \|)$ be a normed space, and let $A, B ⊂ X$ be disjoint convex
sets such that $B$ is closed and $A$ is compact.

Prove that there exists $\varphi ∈ X^*$ such that $$\sup_{a\in A} \operatorname{Re}(\varphi)(a) < \inf_{b\in B} \operatorname{Re}(\varphi)(b).$$

I've been struggling a lot with this question, and would love some guide or help.
My attempt was to use the geometric version of Hahn-Banach theorem, but I couldn't quite get this result. The problem is obviously showing the existence of a functional such that we have "$<$" instead of "$\leq$" using the extra properties of $A,B$.

Any help would be blessed. thanks!

Comment: To separate sets $A$ and $B$ from each other, how about separating the difference set $A - B$ from the singleton $\{0\}$?  That is a set-up for the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: Ya, that's clear, but the Hahn-banach would not give me < but $\leq$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

Let $A - B = \{a-b \;|\; a \in A, b \in B\}$.  Show that $A-B$ is closed, convex, and $0 \notin A - B$.

Since $A-B$ is closed, there is a small $\varepsilon > 0$ so that $T := \{x\in X \;|\; \|x\| < \varepsilon\}$ and $A-B$ are disjoint.  Separate them with a functional.  $T$ is open, so the functional is continuous.  And because of the $\varepsilon$ in the definition of $T$, in fact $A-B$ is *strictly* separated from $\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. The hints were perfect - not showing too much, but giving me enough to work with. I managed to finish by myself. thanks